# Callback is not working in ajax request?

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, axios, draftjs

I am trying to build a contentEditor with draft js. Exactly the feature is Extract the data from url like Facebook. But I am stuck with this part. Callback is not working.

First I wrapped my state with `compositeDecorator` Like this

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const compositeDecorator = new CompositeDecorator([
        .... {
            strategy: linkStrategy,
            component: decorateComponentWithProps(linkComp, {
                passit
            })
        }
        ....
    ]);
}
// This is my strategy
function linkStrategy(contentBlock, callback, contentState) {
    findLinkInText(LINK_REGEX, contentBlock, callback)
}

function findLinkInText(regex, contentBlock, callback) {
    const text = contentBlock.getText();
    let matchArr, start;
    if ((matchArr = regex.exec(text)) !== null) {
        start = matchArr.index;
        let URL = matchArr[0];
        console.log(URL);
        axios.post('/url', {
            url: URL
        }).then(response => {
            passit = response.data
            //not working
            callback(start, start + URL.length)
        })
        //working
        callback(start, start + URL.length)
    }
}
```

If the callback won't work, the component will not render..
I don't know this is a basic javascript problem. But the thing is I want to fetch the url data from my server and I have to pass the data via props to my component and render it.

UPDATE FOR THE ANSWER

```
function findLinkInText(regex, contentBlock, callback) {
    const text = contentBlock.getText();
    let matchArr, start;
    if ((matchArr = regex.exec(text)) !== null) {
        start = matchArr.index;
        let url = matchArr[0];
        axios.post('/url', {
            url: URL
        }).then(response => {
            passit = response.data
            handleWithAxiosCallBack(start, start + matchArr[0].length, callback)
        }).catch(err => console.log(err))
    }
}


function handleWithAxiosCallBack(start, startLength, callback) {
    console.log(callback); //Spits out the function But Not working
    callback(start, startLength)
}
```

Comment: From your example I don't see how you pass callback to `linkStrategy`. please post more details about `strategy:linkStrategy`

Comment: Sir,From LinkStrategy I am passing the callback to other funtion i find the url match from there callback will be executed @MaximShoustin

Comment: @Nane - is your passit variable populated `passit = response.data`. Can you check that in `console.log`.

Comment: My main Aim is to pass the url data to my component And yes passit have some url data that is working I've tested it..@nash_ag

Comment: @MaximShoustin Any suggestion or any alternative method for embeding urls with draft js

Comment: it is not working because it is not defined inside the "then" function.

Comment: So how to do it @Bindrid

Comment: is the .then being called? if so, that is your callback function

Comment: Could Pls Give an example with my Question @Bindrid

Comment: does the server received and responsed the `/url` request?

Comment: Yes That is working I've tested it many times ... @JiangYD

Comment: Seems `draftjs` not support async callback invoking. make a feature request to the `draftjs` team maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below described technique would help you to achieve the behaviour you are expecting.

**Why your solution does not works:** The reason the desired action that needs to be performed by the `callback` is not performing is because, `draft` expects the `callback` to be called synchronous. Since you are using an `async` function(the axios api call) and asynchronously calling the `callback` has no effect.

**Solution:** This may not be a efficient solution, but could get the job done. In simple words, all you have to do is to store the results from the `axios` call in a variable(temporarily) and then trigger the `re-render` for your `editor`, retrieve the result store earlier and use it to call the callback.

I'm following based on this example [here](https://codepen.io/Kiwka/pen/YNYgWa?editors=0010). Assuming that you store the editor state in the component's state. Below is a pseudo-code which you might need to implement as per your needs.

Let's assume your component state is like below which holds the `Editor`'s state.

```
constructor(props){
 super(props);
 // .. your composite decorators

 // this is your component state holding editors state
 this.state = {
  editorState: EditorState.createWithContent(..)
 }

 // use this to temporarily store the results from axios.
 this.tempResults = {}; 

}
```

Assuming you are rendering your `Editor` to something like below. Notice the `ref`. Here the editors reference is stored in the component's `editor` variable which you can access later. Using a string as ref would work, but this is the recommended way to store refs.

```
 <Editor
    ref={ (editor) => this.editor }
    editorState={this.state.editorState}
    onChange={this.onChange}
    // ...your props
 />
```

In your component, write a function to update the editor with currentState which would force the `re-render`. Make sure this function is bound to your component so that we get the correct `this`(context).

```
forceRenderEditor = () => {
  this.editor.update(this.state.editorState);
}
```

In your `findLinkInText` function do the below.

First make sure it(findLinkInText) is bound to your component so we get the correct `this`. You can use arrow function to do this or bind it in the component constructor.

Second, check if we have the result for the `url` already in `tempResults` 
 which we declared in the component's constructor. If we have one, then call the callback immediately with appropriate arguments.

If we don't have a result already, the make the call and store the result in the `tempResults`. After storing, call the already defined `this.forceRenderEditor` method which would invoke draft to re-check and this time, since we have stored the results in the `tempResults`, the callback will be called and appropriate changes would reflect.

```
function findLinkInText(regex, contentBlock, callback) {
 const text = contentBlock.getText();
 let matchArr, start;
 if ((matchArr = regex.exec(text)) !== null) {
     start = matchArr.index;
     let URL = matchArr[0];
     console.log(URL);

     // do we have the result already,?? 
     // call the callback based on the result.
     if(this.tempResults[url]) {
         // make the computations and call the callback() with necessary args
     } else {
     // if we don't have a result, call the api
      axios.post('/url', {
         url: URL
      }).then(response => {
         this.tempResults[url] = response.data;
         this.forceRenderEditor();
         // store the result in this.tempResults and 
         // then call the this.forceRenderEditor
         // You might need to debounce the forceRenderEditor function
      })
    }
 }
}
```

**Note:**

1. You have to determine if you need to clear the tempResults. If so you need to implement the logic for it at the appropriate place.
2. To store the tempResults you can make use of technique called `memoization`. The above described one is a simple one.
3. Since your results are memozied, this might be an advantage for you if the `axios api` call results are not gonna be changing for the same input. You might not have to hit the api again for the same query.
4. The data you store in your tempResults should be the response from the api call or something from which you can determine the arguments that you need to pass to `callback`.
5. I think, you might need to `debounce` the `forceRenderEditor`method to avoid repeated update if there are many api being called for each render.
6. Finally, i could not find a place where `draft` uses or suggests for an `async` callback. You might have to check with the library's team if they support/need such a feature. (If needed make the changes and raise a PR if their team is ok with one.)

**Update**

To bind you can move the functions within the component and write it the below manner.

```
linkStrategy = (contentBlock, callback, contentState) => {
    this.findLinkInText(LINK_REGEX, contentBlock, callback)
}


findLinkInText = (...args) => {
}
```

And in your constructor you can call it like this

```
const compositeDecorator = new CompositeDecorator([
    .... {
        strategy: this.linkStrategy,
        component: decorateComponentWithProps(linkComp, {
            passit
        })
    }
    ....
 ]);
}
```

Or if you want to reuse the function across multiple components then you can bind it in the below manner. But make sure to use the same `state` in all of the sharing components(or use callback to define custom states)

Your constructor will be like

```
const compositeDecorator = new CompositeDecorator([
    .... {
        strategy: linkStrategy.bind(this),
        component: decorateComponentWithProps(linkComp, {
            passit
        })
    }
    ....
 ]);
}
```

Your link strategy will be like this

```
 function linkStrategy(contentBlock, callback, contentState) {
    findLinkInText.call(this,LINK_REGEX, contentBlock, callback);
 }
```

You can use either of the above method to bind your functions.

Comment: Your solution Kinda work But It throws a error Like this **TypeError: _this4.forceRenderEditor is not a function**

Comment: You need to bind `findLinkInText` with the component. or you can use arrow function to do that.  The error occurs because, `findLinkInText` is not in the same context as your component.

Comment: I am sorry I am not good at this I've tried a lot Could you Pls show the example with my  Question..@Panther

Comment: Kinda lame that it passes a callback but expects the function to be synchronous, that's very misleading. Why not return the result? Too simple i guess.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming everything else is working, I would expect something more what is below. I am not set up to use Axios so I can't actually test this.

```
// I made these global variables because you are trying to use them
// in both the .post and the .then
var start; // global variable
var URL // global variable
function processResponse (aStart, aStartURL, passit) {
    // do something with the reponse data
}

function findLinkInText(regex, contentBlock) {
    const text = contentBlock.getText();
    let matchArr;
    if((matchArr = regex.exec(text)) !== null){
        start = matchArr.index;
        // renamed because it is not the url, its data passed to the server
        URL = matchArr[0];
        console.log(URL);
        axios.post('/url',{url:URL}).then(response => {
            passit = response.data;
            processResponse (start, start + URL.length, passit)
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: is the then being called? Is the catch being called?

Comment: See the post I've Updated the code With your Solution Still Not working...

Answer (score -1):

Note that "axios depends on a native ES6 Promise implementation to be supported. If your environment doesn't support ES6 Promises, you can polyfill."  which means that this does not work in all browser. ( I could not get it to work in IE 11 even after include the recommended include here https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise

Here is my code that I did get working in Edge:

```
            axios(
                {
                    method: 'post',
                    url: '/wsService.asmx/GetDTDataSerializedList',
                    data: { parameters: 'one' },
                    callback: function () { alert() }
                })
                  .then(response =>{
                      response.config.callback();

                      console.log(response);
                  })
                  .catch(function (error) {
                      console.log(error);
                  });
             });
```

With that I changed your code accordingly as shown below

```
        function findLinkInText(regex, contentBlock, callback) {
            const text = contentBlock.getText();
            let matchArr, start;
            if ((matchArr = regex.exec(text)) !== null) {
                start = matchArr.index;
                var URL = matchArr[0];
                console.log(URL);

                // I am putting the parameters used to make the call in a JSON object to be used in the "then"
                var myparameters = { myCallback: callback, URL: URL, start: start };

                axios({
                    method:post, 
                    url:'/url',
                    data: { url: URL },
                    // note that i am attaching the callback to be carrired through
                    myParameters: myparameters
                }).then(response => {
                    // This section is the callback generated by the post request. 
                    // it cannot see anything unless they declared globally or attached to the request and passed through
                    // which is what i did.
                    passit = response.data
                    var s = response.config.myParameters.start;
                    var u = response.config.myParameters.URL
                    response.config.myParameters.myCallback(s, s + u.length)
                })

            }
        }
```

Comment: Again No Luck Sir,I could not find any clue !!

Comment: explain no luck.  Did it hot any of the debuggers lines?

Comment: After handleWithAxiosCallBack Nothing is happening